# Android's Encryption mechanism

Tags: encryption, malware, android, url-redirection

Well, according to my Android smartphone, it says the phone has been encrypted. Should I be worried if it has a malware or if I get hacked because I once clicked a link on a certain website then I started getting url redirections to other websites on that browser and some other funny activities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encryption offers no protection against malware or compromise.  Encryption is useful to ensure that if you lose your phone or it is stolen, the person now in possession of the phone will have a much harder time getting your personal data (contacts, emails, calendar, etc.) out of the phone.  Once the phone is booted, the data has been decrypted, and malware can then read the decrypted data.

Comment: And if hacked, what are the likely areas the hacker has access to? E-mails? SD cards? Social sites?

Comment: That would entirely depend on which permissions the malware has been given (remember when you install an app you have to allow it to access certain data?). Furthermore if the malware is able to break out of the sandbox or you are running your android as root, then the malware will be able to access everything.